# how to set mysql max idel by jetty

Tags: jetty

I want to use jetty instead of tomcat, but how to set mysql max idel by jetty?
Environment:spring boot, gradle

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:cc-mysql}:${MYSQL_PORT:3306}/cc
    username: ${MYSQL_USERNAME:root}
    password: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD:root}
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    tomcat:
      max-active: ${MYSQL_MAX_ACTIVE:10}
      max-idle: ${MYSQL_MAX_IDEL:1}
  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please provide specific information about both the language and the frameworks in which you need to specify your database configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The configurations within `spring.datasource.tomcat.*` is for configuring the Tomcat DataSource Pool. (aka `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource`)

A more complete example with the missing (implied?) `spring.datasource.type` option.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: My Example Application
  datasource:
    name: example
    url: jdbc:mysql://dev.mysql.example.com:4444/db?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false
    username: userexample
    password: userpass
    type: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    tomcat:
      max-active: 5
      max-idle: 5
      min-idle: 5
      initial-size: 5
      validation-query: 'select 1'
      test-on-borrow: true
      test-on-return: true
      test-while-idle: true
      max-wait: 15000
```

Jetty doesn't come with a container specific DataSource Pool.

At this point you have two options.

1. Use the mysql datasource directly.  (this is the simplest approach)
2. Use one of the many DataSource pooling libraries out there instead.

If you choose to use a DataSource Pool library, it will have its own configuration that you'll have to learn to to know how to tweak it.  The configuration `max-idle` may not exist, or may even be named differently in that library, or may exist but not be configured via a simple number, or it might refer to minutes (or milliseconds) instead of seconds.